# How to fix 404 Error when deploying SpringBoot App to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to deploy a very basic Spring Boot web app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, It works fine locally, but each time I try to run it on elastic beanstalk I get a 404 error.

Here is my Controller:

```
package com.example.springhelloworld;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String returnHello(){
        return "helloworld";
    }
    
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
package com.example.springhelloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringHelloWorldApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringHelloWorldApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Here is my html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spring App</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome to Spring Hello World!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringHelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringHelloWorld</name>
    <description>SpringHelloWorld</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my project structure:
[image]

I also set server port to 5000 in application.properties file.
I generated the war file using maven and uploaded to Elastic Beantalk using a Tomcat 8.5 platform with Corretto 11. However when I try to access my application I get a 404 error. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Really difficult to tell what the issue is without seeing the ELB configuration. Are you trying to access the app through a load balancer or making the request directly to the ec2 instance?

Comment: Either your application is not deployed correctly or some configuration error. After deployment, do you see a default url that can be access?
What you see in access logs?

Comment: How can I check the access logs?

Comment: @EthanHarris I am making the request directly. What configuration should I look at?

Comment: Nginx on EB runs on port 5000. You need to set your port to 5000 to make the application run.

Comment: @koushikmln I set the port to 5000 in the application.properties file, is there any other configuration I need to do?

Comment: Did you redeploy the application and check if it is working?

Comment: @koushikmln I tried that and It didn't work

Comment: You can ssh into the system and check if the application is running. Alternatively, you can also check which port it is running on. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251584/discussion-between-koushikmln-and-doldrums).

Comment: I'm astonished that this project is even compiling because you are using Spring Boot 3.X which means your minimum reqirement for JDK ist JDK17 but you have configured `<source>8</source>` etc. that does not make sense...